# Grading System Validation using Yii2

Tags: yii2

I am developiging a Grading System as shown below:

[image: Grading System]

**Model**

```
    public static function tableName()
{
    return 'grade_item';
}

public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['grade_max', 'grade_min'], 'required'],
        [['grade_max', 'grade_min'], 'number'],
    ];
}
```

How do I validate, probably from the Model between the grade_min and grade_max. Also, grade_min should not be greater that or equal to grade_max. I want to do it as shown in the diagram below. None of the contents of each row should be the same.

[image: Grading]

Comment: You probably need to write custom validator for such case. You may take a look at https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/pull/15157 - with something like `RequireAnyValidator` there will be possibility to create validation with multiple ways of filing this form (separate range for each grade).

Answer (score 1):

Use [Compare validator](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/tutorial-core-validators#compare)

This validator compares the specified input value with another one and make sure if their relationship is as specified by the operator property.

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['grade_max', 'grade_min'], 'required'],
        [['grade_max', 'grade_min'], 'number'],
        ['grade_max', 'compare', 'compareAttribute' => 'grade_min', 'operator' => '>', 'type' => 'number'],
        ['grade_min', 'compare', 'compareAttribute' => 'grade_max', 'operator' => '<', 'type' => 'number'],
    ];
}
```

Comment: How about if I want it to Validate that it must not allow a number that falls in the range of already existing value. For example if grade_min is 0 and grade_max is 1.99 are already in database. So, if a user enter grade_min or grade_max to be 1.22, it must not allow it.